# create sqlite3 db from sql statements from file in c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to write c++ application to create sqlite db or update existing db from sql statements which are present in text file. I am not able to find right way to do. As a workaround i used system() with "cat sqlfile.txt | sqlite3 mydb
FYI. I am using sqlite3 3071502

Answer (score 1):

You need to use STL fstream library to read the content of file. Tutorials are here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

After that, you need to use sqlite c++ api to execute sql commands. Tutorials are here: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html